# How do I align the div tags inside the td tag so that they are in a line

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align the div tags inside the td, so that they are all inline. I've tried various methods such as using spans, and tinkered around with bootstrap classes but I still couldn't figure it out. Maybe the way I've set of the table is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>TODO supply a title</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <style>
          h4{
              font-size: 2.5vw;
          }
          .container-fluid{
              padding-top: 60px;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <span class="fas fa-home"></span>
                        Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></span></i>Pricing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="badge badge-secondary">5</span>Notifications</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="fas fa-user"></span>Account
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><h4 class="text-center">Free Plan</h4></th>
                            <th><h4 class="text-center">Standard Plan</h4></th>
                            <th><h4 class="text-center">Premium Plan</h4></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td><h3 class="text-center">$0</h3></td>
                          <td><h3 class="text-center">$19.99</h3></td>
                          <td><h3 class="text-center">$29.99</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="d-none d-md-block">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="d-none d-md-block">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="d-none d-md-block">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                              <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Purchase</a></td>
                          <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Purchase</a></td>
                          <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Purchase</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sneh Patel</a>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a picture of the current result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9no8u.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` in association with `flex-direction: row` and `justify-content: space-between`. Check the snipped below:

```html
<html>

<head>
 <style>

 </style>
 <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
  .as-console-wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   max-height: 150px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   border-top: 1px solid #000;
   display: none;
  }

  .as-console {
   background: #e9e9e9;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  .as-console-row {
   display: table-row;
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 13px;
  }

  .as-console-row:after {
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 3px 6px;
   color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   content: attr(data-date);
   vertical-align: top;
  }

  .as-console-row+.as-console-row>* {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  .as-console-row-code {
   width: 100%;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   padding: 3px 5px;
   display: table-cell;
   font-family: monospace;
   font-size: 13px;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .as-console-error:before {
   content: 'Error: ';
   color: #f00;
  }

  .as-console-assert:before {
   content: 'Assertion failed: ';
   color: #f00;
  }

  .as-console-info:before {
   content: 'Info: ';
   color: #00f;
  }

  .as-console-warning:before {
   content: 'Warning: ';
   color: #e90
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes flash {
   0% {
    background: rgba(255, 240, 0, .25);
   }

   100% {
    background: none;
   }
  }

  @-moz-keyframes flash {
   0% {
    background: rgba(255, 240, 0, .25);
   }

   100% {
    background: none;
   }
  }

  @-ms-keyframes flash {
   0% {
    background: rgba(255, 240, 0, .25);
   }

   100% {
    background: none;
   }
  }

  @keyframes flash {
   0% {
    background: rgba(255, 240, 0, .25);
   }

   100% {
    background: none;
   }
  }

  .as-console-row-code,
  .as-console-row:after {
   -webkit-animation: flash 1s;
   -moz-animation: flash 1s;
   -ms-animation: flash 1s;
   animation: flash 1s;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<style>
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .divInfo {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 100%
  }
 }

 @media screen and (min-width: 901px) {
  .div-info {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   width: 100%
  }
 }
</style>

<body>


 <title>TODO supply a title</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
  integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <style>
  h4 {
   font-size: 2.5vw;
  }

  .container-fluid {
   padding-top: 60px;
  }
 </style>


 <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
   aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">
      <span class="fas fa-home"></span>
      Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></span>Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="badge badge-secondary">5</span>Notifications</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="fas fa-user"></span>Account
     </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>
        <h4 class="text-center">Free Plan</h4>
       </th>
       <th>
        <h4 class="text-center">Standard Plan</h4>
       </th>
       <th>
        <h4 class="text-center">Premium Plan</h4>
       </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <h3 class="text-center">$0</h3>
       </td>
       <td>
        <h3 class="text-center">$19.99</h3>
       </td>
       <td>
        <h3 class="text-center">$29.99</h3>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between;">
         <div class="div-info">
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between; width:100%">
         <div class="div-info">
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between; width:100%">
         <div class="div-info">
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
          <div class="col">Lorem ipsum</div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Purchase</a></td>
       <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Purchase</a></td>
       <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Purchase</a></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sneh Patel</a>
 </nav>


 <script type="text/javascript">

 </script>

 <div class="as-console-wrapper">
  <div class="as-console"></div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `<td class="d-none d-md-block" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between;">` Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have updated the snippet. Sorry for the first answer, I got a problem on the resolution, so I couldn't understand the layout.

Comment: Alright so that solves the problem of aligning them, but now the pages isn't responsive. Making the window smaller cuts of the Premium Plan

Comment: I have added the proper CSS to make it responsive.